# Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point ///

Tags: compiler-errors

what should i do when this error appears?

```
"Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS5001  Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point exercise 1  C:\Users\yona\source\repos\exercise 1\exercise 1\CSC    1   Active"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your project might be configured as an executable. In this case it expects to have a main() method that would serve as an entry point.
If the application is configured as a library (dynamic or static), then it would not need an default entry point, meaning you would not need a main() method.